# eslint why does my plugin show Definition for rule was not found?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, eslint

my plugin

@bluelovers/eslint-plugin
https://github.com/bluelovers/ws-node-bluelovers/tree/master/packages/eslint-plugin

my base config
https://github.com/bluelovers/ws-node-bluelovers/blob/master/packages/eslintrc/.eslintrc.json

runtime user config

```
{
  "extends": [
    "bluelovers"
  ]
}
```

i can type in user repo

```
eslint --print-config .
```

this can show config and didn't error, i also see my plugin config inside the list

```
   "@bluelovers/no-irregular-whitespace": [
      "error",
      {
        "skipComments": true,
        "skipStrings": false,
        "skipTemplates": false,
        "skipRegExps": false,
        "ignores": [
          "　"
        ]
      }
    ],
```

but when i type `eslint index.ts`, it show error

```
   1:1   error    Definition for rule '@bluelovers/no-irregular-whitespace' was not found  @bluelovers/no-irregular-whitespace
```

index.ts

```
export const r = /[ \t\uFEFF\xA0　]+$/;

const IRREGULAR_WHITESPACE = /[\f\v  ᠎           ​  　]+/mgu;
```

how can i fix this??

Comment: At least in my case this was not a configuration issue and could be resolved by simply restarting VS Code. So before you start digging in the documentation of a dozen eslint plugins, you might want to give that a try. I'll just leave this here as a hint.

Comment: @bluelovers did you get an answer to this? I see that you have removed the eslintrc from your project. Im stuck on the same issue.

Answer (score 11):

I think the key missing piece is no "plugins" section in config.

---

Why are you extending from "bluelovers"? Do you have a shared config published? It seems like you're working on a plugin, not a config.

You're then using a rule "@bluelovers/no-irregular-whitespace", with a leading @.

If your plugin is published as "@bluelovers/eslint-plugin", you should try something like this:

```
{
    "plugins": ["@bluelovers"],
    "extends": ["@bluelovers"], // Assuming you have @bluelovers/eslint-config published, otherwise this might look different or could be skipped
    "rules": {
        "@bluelovers/no-irregular-whitespace": ["error"]
    }
}
```

Comment: i have both, plugin and config, and plugin field is set on config

Comment: eslint-config-bluelovers , @bluelovers/eslint-plugin

Answer (score 9):

It means eslint cannot find rules in your `index.js`. Try having a look at your `index.js`-exports. They should look something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  rules: {
    [myRuleName]: myRule
  }
};
```

And not like this:

```
exports.default = {
  rules: {
    [myRuleName]: myRule
  }
};
```

If you're using TypeScript, change your export in `index.ts` from `export default {...}` to `export = {...}`.

Comment: Is this answer already outdated? The [documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/working-with-rules) provides an example for a rule, but the keyword `rules` appears nowhere in that article.

Comment: That link does not mention `rules` which is confusing, this [one](https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/working-with-plugins) specifically about working with plugins talks about `rules`

Comment: What if your project doesn't have an index.js?

Comment: Not sure where index.js came from. Afaik `.eslintrc.js` should be the filename for eslint configuration.